# Como baixar imagens sequencialmente de um site usando WGet?

Tags: windows, cmd, wget

Preciso saber onde está o erro no comando:

```
 wget http://shadowera.com/cards/se{001..200}.jpg
```

Utilizei o site "shadowera" para teste.
Preciso saber como salvar várias imagens de uma só vez, e dessa forma não está funcionando.

Comment: Esse `wget` no Windows é o mesmo GNU Wget [só que portado, ou usado via Cygwin]? Se for, [esses exemplos de uso](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Examples) podem resolver. Experimente `wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A se[0-2][0-9][0-9].gif  http://shadowera.com/cards/`

Comment: É o GNU. O comando não baixa nada, ele apenas cria a pasta com o nome do site, mas vazia.

Comment: Estou usando o cmd

Comment: experimente usar shell, pois esse tipo de expansão {001..200} nao funciona em cmd. Em cmd você poderia usar for, mas ai iria de 1 a 200 e não de 001 a 200.

Comment: Consegui fazer usando o Cygwin. Parece que o problema é realmente o CMD. Brigadão

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solução

Antes de usar este loop, digite `cmd /v` no console para habilitar a expansão de parâmetros:

```
set i=1000 && for /l %a in (1,1,200) do (
   set /a "i=!i!+1" && wget http://shadowera.com/cards/se!i:~1,3!.jpg )
```

A quebra de linha é para facilitar a leitura apenas.

### Explicação

Como estamos usando o CMD, e não um Shell, a expansão `{001..200}` não funciona. A solução encontrada foi um `for`.

```
for /l %a in (1,1,200) do ( ...comandos... )
```

O problema inicial é que o máximo que um `for` normal do CMD nos daria, seria uma contagem de 1 a 200, e não de 001 a 200, que é a saída necessária para o problema, dado que os arquivos são `se001.jpg` a `se200.jpg`, e não `se1.jpg` em diante.

Então, a solução simples seria contar de 1001 a 1200 e aproveitar os últimos três digitos apenas. Para isso, a idéia inicial seria utilizar as substrings do CMD:

```
%variavel:~posicaoinicial,final%
```

Como nada é simples, infelizmente as substrings do CMD só funcionam pra variáveis de ambiente "convencionais", e não se aplicam à do for, `%a` no caso.

Para isto, utilizamos uma variável adicional, `i`, iniciando por 1000, e a incrementamos durante o loop. Para manter tudo em uma linha só, usamos o `&&` (and)  para concatenar os comandos.

```
set i=1000 && ..for.. ( set /a "i=%i%+1 ..
```

Mas... Isto não funciona!

Não funciona, pois a atribuição dos sets é feita primeiro, e ele vai executar o comando seguinte com os valores errados.

A solução: iniciar um CMD com flag `/V`, que ativa a expansão atrasada da variável, que resolve nosso problema. Para isto usamos o formato `!variavel!` no lugar de `%variável%`

O resultado é o comando composto, do início da resposta.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, amigo.
Poderia explicar o seu código?

Vlw

Comment: Excelente @Bacco. Mto bem explicado.
Agradeço em nome de todos que se interessaram pela pergunta.

Vlw...