# Ocultar nomes dos arquivos na hora da compactação

Tags: cmd, arquivo-zip

Estou usando a sintaxe abaixo para zipar arquivos.

```
7z u -t7z destino\arquivo.7z origem\arquivo.*.
```

O parâmetro `u` faz com o `7z.exe` compacte apenas os arquivos modificados.
A minha duvida é que quando executo esse comando via prompt de comando, ele aparece os nomes dos arquivos que estão sendo compactados.

Existe alguma maneira de como fazer essa compactação no CMD de modo oculto? Ou seja, sem que o usuário veja quais arquivos estão sendo compactados?

Comment: Ao meu ver a questão é sobre linha de comando (como o ap solicitou "como fazer essa compactação no `CMD` de modo oculto") e a comunidade mostrou-se bastante tolerante em questões semelhantes (sobre linha de comando), exemplo de situação: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13945/3635 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21655/existe-um-sudo-para-windows

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Essas duas questões que você mencionou envolvem programação de batches. Já esta aqui não.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Mas ela já está fechada! Bom, sobre aceitar ou não perguntas como as do site SuperUser, isso já foi proposto aqui, e a comunidade até agora não abraçou a ideia.

Comment: Mas como eu já havia te dito, esse debate sempre é válido. Se quiser pode reacender uma das discussões sobre o assunto no meta (como [esta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98/perguntas-gerais-sobre-computadores-no-t%C3%B3pico), [esta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112/stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-%C3%A9-somente-o-stackoverflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-ou-%C3%A9-mais-abr) e [esta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1367/super-user-em-portugu%C3%AAs)), ou abrir uma nova.

Comment: Debate: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2471/3635

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme está resposta no [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/194661/162728), basta você adicionar `> NUL:` no final no comando, ficaria algo assim:

```
7z u -t7z destino\arquivo.7z origem\arquivo.*. > NUL:
```

Note que ele oculta tudo.

Outra resposta interessante é esta no [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/468505/162728):

É altamente recomendável que você visualize o estado do processo. Para ignorar a maioria das mensagens e deixar somente as de confirmação use:

```
7z u -t7z destino\arquivo.7z origem\arquivo.*. | findstr /b /r /c:"\<Everything is Ok" /c:"\<Scanning" /c:"\<Creating archive"
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda valeu